# What is wrong with my below code for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the day and date in following format but it doesn't work for me. Error showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". Can anyone get me out of this?

**Output:-**

Today is : Wednesday

Current time is : 8 PM :25:20

** My HTML Code:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Excercise</title>
    <script src="Js\DateTimeExcercise.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
      Today is : <span id="day"></span>
      <br/><br/>
      Current time is : <span id="time"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

** My Java Script Code:-**

```js
var day, time, Sec, Min, Hr, AMPM;
AMPM = "AM";

day = new Date().getDay();

Sec = new Date().getSeconds();
Min = new Date().getMinutes();
Hr = new Date().getHours();

if (Hr>12)
{
  Hr = Hr - 12;
  AMPM = "PM";
}
switch(day)
{
      case 0:
      txt = "Sunday";
      break;

      case 1:
      txt = "Monday";
      break;

      case 2:
      txt = "Tueday";
      break;

      case 3:
      txt = "Wednesday";
      break;

      case 4:
      txt = "Thrusday";
      break;

      case 5:
      txt = "Friday";
      break;

      case 6:
      txt = "Saturday";
      break;

}
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = txt;

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Hr + " "+ AMPM + " "+ ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;
```

Comment: DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: you  have to add the script tag just before the closing </body> tag

Comment: You can try to wrap your code with this to check when the document is ready:

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        // put your code here   
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the script at the bottom of the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Excercise</title>
</head>
<body>
  Today is : <span id="day"></span>
  <br/><br/>
  Current time is : <span id="time"></span>
</body>
<script src="Js\DateTimeExcercise.js">
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks it works for me, can explain me what is the difference calling before and after the script?

Comment: @YashwantSingh The difference is that when you run the script first, the elements don't exist on the page yet

Comment: Ok, new lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

You load the script before the DOM is rendered. So it's better to place the script tag below all your code, just above the body tag. Right now the code cant find the elements yet

Another possibility is to wrap your code in a event listener, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.