# Unable to access DOM elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have an HTML page with many buttons in separate div tags. When one of the buttons is clicked I disable the other buttons and make the background color of the div with the selected button yellow.
All this was working fine but all has stopped working now (I have made many changes and can't track what has gone wrong). I checked and my document.getElementById(id) returns a null.
All the solutions I have checked here say that this happens if the element is accessed before being created. But how can this be true if I am clicking the button and all the code is working correctly excepting manipulating the DOM elements.

I am lost as how to find the problem. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Part of my code here

```js
function anyLogging() {
  toastMessage("Tracking Started. Dont forget to stop when done");
  tLogger.startTripPressed = true;
  tLogger.stopTripPressed = false;
  tLogger.loggingData = true;
  document.getElementById("walking-start").disabled = true;
  $('#walking-start').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#bus-start').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#cycling-start').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#car-start').prop('disabled', true);
  markRow();
}

function anyLoggingStopped() {
  unmarkRow();
  tLogger.mode = "";
  tLogger.startTripPressed = false;
  tLogger.stopTripPressed = true;
  tLogger.loggingData = false;
  $('#walking-start').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#bus-start').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#cycling-start').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#car-start').prop('disabled', false);


}

function markRow() {
  var row = tLogger.mode;
  console.log(row);
  divName = "#" + row + "-section";
  console.log(divName);
  $(divName).css('background', 'yellow');
}

function unmarkRow() {
  var row = tLogger.mode;
  console.log(row);
  divName = "#" + row + "-section";
  $(divName).css('background', 'white');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="walking-section" style="height:90px;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h6 class="padding-lr" style="">Walking</h6>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="img/walk2.png" width="24" height="24">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-2">
      <button id="walking-start" class="btn-danger btn-lg custom-prop" style="background-color:#2c742a;">
                                        Start
                                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4">
      <button id="walking-stop" class="btn-danger btn-lg custom-prop" style="background-color:#33506e;">
                                        Stop
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="msg-board-walking">
    <p id="msg-board-walking-p">

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bus-section" style="height:90px;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h6 class="padding-lr" style="font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;">On the Bus</h6>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="img/bus2.png" width="24" height="24">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-2">
      <button id="bus-start" class="btn-danger btn-lg custom-prop" style="background-color:#2c742a;">
                                        Start
                                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4">
      <button id="bus-stop" class="btn-danger btn-lg custom-prop" style="background-color:#33506e;">
                                Stop
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="msg-board-bus">
    <p id="msg-board-bus-p">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I said all other functionality is working except .prop() and .css() methods. The same is happening with .hide() and .show() on other pages. I think its something very basic that I am missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my below code for javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955697/what-is-wrong-with-my-below-code-for-javascript)

Comment: Your code is not complete. There are no event handlers assigned and toastMessage is also not defined. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I dont know about your full code, but here I don't see any off your functions being called.

Comment: I just gave a part of my code to give the idea. Its in a big project where pages are loaded in the DOM dynamically. Its impossible to put the whole thing here but I iwll try to put a minimal version of it.

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: No. It just ignores everything. Must be something stupid that I have done but I can't seem to debug the problem. I added iscroll 4.2 to my project. If that gives you guys any leads. https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

Comment: i tried                                                                                                      element = document.getElementById('walking-start');
    console.log(element);                                                                                     the console output is                                              <button id="walking-start" class="btn-danger btn-lg custom-prop ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" style="background-color:#2c742a;" disabled="">

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem at last. I had a function for dynamically loading a page in the pagecontainer. On the main page I had a nav-panel with the event listener.

main.js file

```
$(document).on("click", "#record-trip", function(){
        console.log("click registered");
        loadPage("page-trip-logger");
    });
```

In the `page-trip-logger`  I copy pasted the event listener from the main page so the loadPage() function was duplicated.

Inside the trip-logger.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", "#nearest-stops", function(){
        console.log("click registered");
        loadPage("page-bus-schedule");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#record-trip", function(){
        console.log("click registered");
        loadPage("page-trip-logger");
    });
});
```

I think when I pressed the button to load the page due to bounce effect the `loadPage("page-trip-logger");` was fired again and so I had two pages loaded in my pagecontainer with the same ID. All the manipulation of css was done, but inside the page which was hidden by the second reload.

Need to refine my loadPage function and stop copy pasting the nav-bar code.